# Creating delete button for table with a postgres database table

Tags: php, postgresql

The database I'm using is postgres. The database connection is located in the config.php and it works because I used it to populate the table. However, I can't seem to get the delete button to work. This is for internal use so I'm not really worried about sql injection so the database structure is built without id as primary key. So the first field in the table called common_name is unique so I'm using that as the reference for the delete button.

readme-p.php:

```
<?php

//the following php code is for displaying the table contents on the same page

include 'config.php';

$query = 'select * from ReadMe';

$result = pg_query($query);


$i = 0;

// code for creating a table structure using css

echo '<html><body><style>
table, td, th {
    border: 0.5px solid #D96B27;
    text-align: left;
}

th, td {
    padding: 10px;
} </style><table><tr>';


//fetching the column names of the db table

while ($i < pg_num_fields($result))
{
  $fieldName = pg_field_name($result, $i);
  echo '<th>' . $fieldName . '</th>';
  $i = $i + 1;
}
echo '</tr>';
$i = 0;

//fetching and displaying the contents of the db table


while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  $count = count($row);
  $y = 0;
  while ($y < $count)
  {
    $c_row = current($row);
    echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';
    next($row);
    $y = $y + 1;
  }
  // Adds the Edit and Delete buttons to every row
  echo "<form action=\"readme-p-delete.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "\" method=\"post\">";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value=" . $row['name'] .">";
  echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" style='color:#0090C1;' value=\"Edit\"></td>";
  echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\" style='color:#E63462;'></form></td></tr>";

  $i = $i + 1;
}
pg_free_result($result);

echo '</table></body></html>';

//Delete button function


?>
```

readme-p-delete.php:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

sql = "DELETE FROM readme WHERE common_name='$_POST[name]'";
$result = pg_query($sql);

pg_free_result($result);
header('location: readme-p.php');
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're readme table actually looks like but you're posting the value of the column 'name' ( $row['name'] ) and trying to delete based on the column 'common_name'.

Comment: This is unsafe SQL to begin with, I suggest learning about bind variables which completely kill most sql injection attacks, and make easier to read code (IMO)

Comment: Example SQL injection on your form. 
Consider if $_POST['name'] = "' or '1'='1"
Your SQL becomes
Delete from readme where common_name='' or '1'='1'

which will delete every row in the table

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'select * from ReadMe';
sql = "DELETE FROM readme WHERE common_name='$_POST[name]'";
```

You work with different tables ReadMe and readme. Is it ok?

Comment: That part isn't an issue.